# Redirecting stdout to a file in awk

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I am trying to write an awk command to take certain fields out of one file and write them to a new file. I am able to to separate the fields (comma delineate) and print it to stdout but I can't figure out how to get it into the new file in the correct format. Here is my current command:

```
$ awk '{FS =","};{print $3}' test.log > test1.log
```

This puts the third field of each line in the new file but inserts 2 blank lines at the beginning of the new file and then a blank line in between each field. I would also like the keep the comma separators but can't figure that out ether. I'm fairly new to bash and awk so any help is appreciated!

Here a chunk of my sample data:

```
10.60.3.109, anonymous, 12/1/2003, 6:56:20, MSFTPSVC1, CSS, ipaddr, 0, 0, 0, 331, 0, [3007]USER, anonymous, -,
10.60.3.109, -, 12/1/2003, 6:56:20, MSFTPSVC1, CSS, ipaddr, 0, 0, 0, 530, 1326, [3007]PASS, IEUser@, -,
10.60.3.109, anonymous, 12/1/2003, 6:56:20, MSFTPSVC1, CSS, ipaddr, 0, 0, 0, 331, 0, [3008]USER, anonymous, -,
10.60.3.109, -, 12/1/2003, 6:56:20, MSFTPSVC1, CSS, ipaddr, 0, 0, 0, 530, 1326, [3008]PASS, IEUser@, -,
10.60.3.109, anonymous, 12/1/2003, 6:56:20, MSFTPSVC1, CSS, ipaddr, 0, 0, 0, 331, 0, [3009]USER, anonymous, -,
10.60.3.109, -, 12/1/2003, 6:56:20, MSFTPSVC1, CSS, ipaddr, 0, 0, 0, 530, 1326, [3009]PASS, IEUser@, -,
10.60.3.109, sally, 12/1/2003, 6:56:26, MSFTPSVC1, CSS, ipaddr, 0, 0, 0, 331, 0, [3010]USER, sally, -,
10.60.3.109, -, 12/1/2003, 6:56:26, MSFTPSVC1, CSS, ipaddr, 16, 0, 0, 530, 1326, [3010]PASS, -, -,
10.60.3.109, sally, 12/1/2003, 6:56:31, MSFTPSVC1, CSS, ipaddr, 0, 0, 0, 331, 0, [3011]USER, sally, -,
10.60.3.109, -, 12/1/2003, 6:56:31, MSFTPSVC1, CSS, ipaddr, 31, 0, 0, 530, 1326, [3011]PASS, -, -,
10.60.3.109, sally, 12/1/2003, 6:56:36, MSFTPSVC1, CSS, ipaddr, 0, 0, 0, 331, 0, [3012]USER, sally, -,
10.60.3.109, -, 12/1/2003, 6:56:36, MSFTPSVC1, CSS, ipaddr, 15, 0, 0, 530, 1326, [3012]PASS, -, -,
10.60.3.109, sally, 12/1/2003, 6:56:40, MSFTPSVC1, CSS, ipaddr, 0, 0, 0, 331, 0, [3013]USER, sally, -,
10.60.3.109, sally, 12/1/2003, 6:56:40, MSFTPSVC1, CSS, ipaddr, 0, 0, 0, 230, 0, [3013]PASS, -, -,
10.60.3.109, sally, 12/1/2003, 6:56:40, MSFTPSVC1, CSS, ipaddr, 0, 0, 0, 331, 0, [3014]USER, sally, -,
10.60.3.109, sally, 12/1/2003, 6:56:40, MSFTPSVC1, CSS, ipaddr, 0, 0, 0, 230, 0, [3014]PASS, -, -,
10.60.3.109, sally, 12/1/2003, 6:56:47, MSFTPSVC1, CSS, ipaddr, 0, 0, 0, 331, 0, [3015]USER, sally, -,
```

Comment: If you are grabbing just one column what is the use of `,` separators? Can you post some sample input data and your expected output?

Comment: In the end I be copying several fields over. In the original file there each field is separated by a comma with no space.

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}{ print $1, $2, $4 }' test.log > test1.log` will allow you to keep the `,` delimiter when you decide to extract multiple columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{FS =","};{print $3}' test.log > test1.log
```

The first action is `{FS = ","}` and it is being executed for each line.  It should probably be preceded by `BEGIN`.  Because the field separator is currently not set until after the first line is already read and split, the first line is most likely read as a single field, and hence `$3` is empty, leading to the blank line.

The second action is `;`, which <s>prints the entire line</s> doesn't seem to do anything.  You don't normally use a semicolon like that; it normally only appears inside the braces of an action.

The third action is `{print $3}`, which prints the 3rd field (when there is a third field to print).

I'm not yet sure I understand the double blank line at the beginning of your output, unless there's a blank line at the beginning of your input.  Nor am I reproducing the alternating blank lines, this using the BSD `awk` from Mac OS X 10.10.1 Yosemite, but also using GNU `awk` 3.1.7.

You probably want:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = ","} {print $3}' test.log > test1.log
```

or (preferable in my view):

```
awk -F"," '{print $3}' test.log > test1.log
```

where the quotes around the comma are optional (since comma is not a shell metacharacter).  But if you're later going to be selecting multiple fields, you probably want to do as [jaypal singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/970195/jaypal-singh) suggested in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28133574/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-in-awk/28133606#comment44639709_28133574), and use:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS = FS = ","} {print $3, $5, $9}' test.log > test1.log
```

for whatever permutation of the fields you want printed.

Comment: This does fix the extra lines on top of the new file but it still inserts blank lines in between. Any idea why?

Comment: @Rostro: Does your data come from DOS (Windows) and have CRLF line endings?  Or does your data have alternating data lines and blank lines? Clutching at straws here.  Quick experimentation with a DOS format file doesn't show a problem.

Comment: Mine does not have DOS line endings just LF. How would this make a difference?

Comment: @Rostro: like I said, I'm clutching at straws.  And as I noted in an update to my comment, CRLF doesn't seem to make a difference for me anyway.  (My test data file had lines `a,b,c,d` then `1,2,3,4` then `a,b,c,d` again, with Unix or DOS line endings.)  I can explain one blank line at the beginning; I can't explain the alternating field 3 lines and blank lines.  Can you show the first 10 lines, say, of your sample data?

Comment: Updated the original question with a sample. I redacted IP addresses with the text "ipaddr".

Comment: OK.  Are you on a Unix-like system or on a Windows system?  Which version of `awk` are you using?  I'm still suspicious that the semicolon is the cause of the blank lines.  Do they appear if you omit the semicolon from your script?

Comment: It's a Unix system an Ubuntu server to be exact . I am using GNU Awk 3.1.8 . It still happens with the semicolon omitted.

Comment: Interesting.  On my Ubuntu 14.04, `awk` is a link to `/etc/alternatives/awk` which in turn links to `/usr/bin/mawk`, which declines to identify a version.  Your data shown in the question has large numbers of spaces in it, so when I try your script, it prints a value for $3 (which is `12/1/2003,` for the fragment shown) as the first line.  I'm no longer even sure I can explain your blank line output — unless you're not showing the genuine log file. I got `gawk` 4.0.1 when I installed `gawk` on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69541/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-rostro).

Comment: This should do too:  `awk -F, '{print $3}' test.log > test1.log`

Comment: Ok so I poked around and figured out that I was somehow using a copy of the original file that had been modified to have blank lines. So my original data set was skewed. Sorry for making such a stupid mistake! You did clear up the problem with the semicolon. Thanks for the help!